# Is there any difference in meaning between "bring on" and "bring about" in the sense of causing someone?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference in meaning between "bring on" and "bring about" in the sense of causing someone? For example:

> The pandemic has **brought about**/**brought on** a lot of change.
>
> The desease can **bring about**/**bring on** some complications.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is minor difference.

**Bring about** means *to cause to take place* or *effect*. [bring about](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bring%20about).

The first sentence would be more correct as follows -

- The pandemic has *brought about* a lot of change.

This is more appropriate because the pandemic has caused the changes to take place.

**Bring on** means *to cause to appear* or *occur*. [bring on](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bring%20on)

The second sentence would be more correct as follows -

- The disease can bring on some complications.

This is more appropriate because the disease has caused the complications to occur.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still cannot see the difference in meaning. Both difinition are basically the same to me, abeit the word choice for them different.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope Well you can say they are synonymous, but word choice matters from sentence to sentence. You need to use the word which seems to be more fit for the situation.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh I don't follow the logic of your answer. In both cases the illness causes the changes but you suggest different prepositions. As I understand, to **bring about** is to cause to happen; **to bring on** is to lead to, to stimulate - rather than to cause. The two meanings are narrowly separated.

Comment: @RonaldSole Very well. I agree. Hence I said they might be synonymous. Going with your logic, the second statement is well versed since, the disease is stimulating the complications, whereas the pandemic is causing the problems.

Comment: Gardeners bring on plants; teachers bring on promising pupils.